# Is there any way to allow users to select a blank value from angular dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have a form with a save button which is being disable using **$pristine** and **$invalid** properties. Form has a drop down menu which contains a blank value as Select option. Once I selected the blank value it always sets the from's $invalid property to false. Could anyone suggest me an option?

My save button code like this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary app-form-buttons" disabled="disabled" name="btnSave" ng-     disabled="myForm.$pristine || myForm.$invalid" type="submit">
    <i class="icon-save"></i>
</button>
```

Drop down code like this

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-11">
  <select class="form-control" name="Type" ng-model="bus.route" required ng-options="bus.type as type.Type for type in types" >
    <option>---Please Choose---</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved. I was trying to validate the form using required attribute. Which had gave me an invalid error when I select the blank value. To overcome the problem I used custom method inside disable attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you need is to set the placeholder option  to disabled as you don't want it to be selected.

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-11">
   <select class="form-control" name="Type" ng-model="bus.route" ng-options="bus.type as type.Type for type in types" >
       <option disabled>---Please Choose---</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem is still there, because select has required attribute